# How would I convert a value of 2.30 (two minutes and thirty seconds) to just integer seconds

Tags: java, time, floating-point

Let me know please if i can be more specific.

I've tried multiplying and dividing but haven't been able to figure anything out.

Comment: 2.30 decimal is not 2 ' 30''. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes. They aren't separate.

Comment: 2.30 is not a valid float

Comment: If you are given a float value of 2.30, that isn't a valid representation in Java time formatting of 2' 30" (two minutes thirty seconds). It's 2.30 seconds -- a big difference! If you said that the 2.30 was a String value, the yes, it might mean 2' 30". But the unit delimiter should be a colon (":"). So, what is the actual data type?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is that 2.30 is not exactly representable as a float; this is resolved by round().  The trailing 0 is also an issue; this is resolved by * 100:

```
>>> v=2.30
>>> v
2.3
>>> v=v*100
>>> v
229.99999999999997
>>> v=round(v,2)
>>> v
230.0
>>> sec = v%100
>>> sec
30.0
>>> min = (v-v%100)/100
>>> min
2.0
>>> int = sec + min * 60
>>> int
150.0
>>>
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If 2.3 is a float, and the units are seconds, that's 2 and 30/100 seconds, not 2 and 50/100 seconds. If the value is "2.30" where the "." is the unit delimiter (not correct in Java time formatting; should be a colon, ":"), then yes, you could argue that it represents 2' 30". If that's the case, you have to split the string using "." as the delimiter (result = [ 2, 30 ]) and treat each item differently: (2*60) + 30 = 150.